# How to construct object in function using key passed as argument

Tags: json, jq

I frequently need to create reusable function that performs transformations for a given field of input, for example:

```
def keep_field_only(field):
  {field}
;
```

or

```
def count_by(field):
  group_by(field) |
  map(
    {
      field: .[0].field,
      count: length
    }
  )
;
```

While `group_by` works fine with key passed as an argument, using it to construct object (eg. to keep only key in the object) doesn't work.

I believe it can be always worked around using `path/1`, but in my experience it significantly complicates code.

Other workaround I used is copying field `+{new_field: field}` at beginning of function, deleting it in the end, but it doesn't look very efficient or readable either.

Is there a shorter and more readable way?

**Update:**

Sample input:

```
[
  {"type":1, "name": "foo"},
  {"type":1, "name": "bar"},
  {"type":2, "name": "joe"}
]
```

Preferred function invocation and expected results:

```
.[] | keep_field_only(.type):

  {"type": 1}
  {"type": 1}
  {"type": 2}
```

---

```
 count_by(.type):
 
 [
   {"type":1, "count": 2},
   {"type":2, "count": 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Please give some sample input and output. I'm imagining input like `[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":1},{"id":2}]` and counting by `.id`

Comment: @glennjackman Updated question with sample input, preferred invocation and results of respective functions.

Comment: Why do you need a method such as `keep_field_only`? `.[] | keep_field_only(.type)` is not any shorter than `.[] | {type}`

Comment: Your `count_by` doesn't work for me. It will always return `{field:null,count:…}`. It must be `.[0]|field`, not `.[0].field`

Comment: `keep_field_only` is a simplified example of more complicated functions that involve key-specific manipulating with input.

Comment: Yes, `count_by` as defined in question does not work. I just outlined the way such function could ideally look like, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: @wassrubleff would your complicated function still work if changed to accept the reduced object already? So `keep_fields_only({type})` instead of `keep_fields_only(.type)`? Perhaps that simplifies its implementation

Answer (score 2):

You can define **pick/1** as below,

```
def pick(paths):
  . as $in
  | reduce path(paths) as $path (null;
    setpath($path; $in | getpath($path))
  );
```

and use it like so:

```
.[] | pick(.type)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/W33GXhDUW64)</sup>

```
def count_by(paths; filter):
  group_by(paths | filter) | map(
    (.[0] | pick(paths)) + {count: length}
  );
def count_by(paths):
  count_by(paths; .);
count_by(.type)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XYCGiQql-rO)</sup>

I don't think there's a *shorter and more readable way*.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you can use path/1 to define your `keep_field_only` and `count_by`, but it can be done in a very simple way:

```
def keep_field_only(field):
  (null | path(field)[0]) as $field
  | {($field): field} ;

def count_by(field):
  (null | path(field)[0]) as $field
  | group_by(field)
  | map(
    {
      ($field): .[0][$field],
      count: length
    }
  );
```

Of course this is only intended to work in examples like yours, e.g. with invocations like `keep_field_only(.type)` or `count_by(.type)`.
However, thanks to `setpath`, the same technique can be used in more complex cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code still looks quite complicated, though. Subfunctions like pick/1 above can be a workaround.